# Replacing product name/title in woocommerce with custom input field

Tags: woocommerce

Can anyone tell me how I can replace the product name in woocommerce with a custom field...???

**Example:**

Let's say I have named a product "Product1". The customer then adds a name on the product page in a field, "Products2". Then I want this name to appear as the product name on the cart, checkout and thank you page.

Could I do something like this:

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_product_title', 'add_custom_name' );
   function add_custom_name( $title ) {

   }
```

Comment: are you asking to change product title at front end and replace name by custom field?

Comment: Have you tried [Product Add-Ons](https://woocommerce.com/products/product-add-ons/)?

Comment: Yes, i am trying to change product title at the front end and replace it by using a custom field. Have tried product add-ons, but it cannot do it.